# Does Hextech Gunblade heal passive stack with that of Will of the Ancients?

Tags: league-of-legends

Hextech Gunblade has a unique passive which heals for a portion of damage dealt, as described in-game:

> Heal for 15% of damage dealt. This is 33% as effective for Area of Effect damage.

Will of the Ancients has a very similar unique passive:

> Your spells and abilities heal you for 15% of the damage dealt, calculated before you target's resistances. This effect is reduced to one third for AoE effects.

I thought that these passives seemed too similar to stack (and maybe be too overpowered if they stacked), and so checked the wiki.
Hextech Gunblade is listed as having a unique passive called Omnivore:

> UNIQUE – OMNIVORE: Instantly heal for 15% of all damage dealt, including physical, magical and true damage.
>   Area of effect damage only heals 5% for every unit affected.

Will of the Ancients is not listed as having this named passive Omnivore, yet on the [page for Omnivore](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Named_item_effect#Omnivore), one of the items listed as having it *is* Will of the Ancients (and to add to the confusion more, it says "not uniquely named, but same effect" and "pending for test").

This is all rather baffling. **Is there a concrete answer as to whether the Hextech Gunblade healing passive and Will of the Ancients healing passive stack?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way Unique passives work is quite strange yet logical.

The passive with the same names don't stack, for instance trinity force, frozen gauntlet or lich bane (same unique passive called Spellblade).

The passive that only have the UNIQUE passive statement mean that you can't stack multiple times the SAME item to get this passive.

Fortunately, if you buy a different item the passive WILL STACK.

So for your question, YES hextech gunblade and Will of Ancient should stack on their passive (the same way bloodthirster and BRK stack for instance). Every element is respected in the multiple passive rule : different name, different item.

PS: didn't retry it in game since last patch but if it doesn't stack you may want report a bug to Riot.

Comment: But Spellblade from different items such as Lich Bane and Trinity Force will not stack. (Also Hextech Gunblade and Will of the Ancients passive is not spell vamp, it was changed some patches ago)

Comment: Yeh this is what I said, the passive Spellblade got a name. But the Will of ancient got no name on the passive, so if it does not stack with hextech gunblade it is a bug!

Comment: Oh right, never mind me not being able to read...

Comment: let me make it a little clearer